# Sharing button is not visible in lightning in case object

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, sharing, sharerecord

I have installed a component called Lightning sharing to make sharing button visible for all objects in lightning. But the sharing button in not visible on case object. But it is visible in contact ,account object and in custom objects.I followed the steps as mentioned in the link below.

https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/the-sharing-button-is-not-available-in-the-salesforce-lightning-experience-ui-heres-a-solution-for-this/

Kindly help me out how to make the sharing button visible for case object.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing button only shows when Sharing of an object is private, so please make sure that Case object should have private sharing.

Setup -> Quick Find -> Sharing settings -> Case (it should be private.)

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here is that there **is still *NO* Sharing button in the Lightning UI**.  See this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339349&type=1&mode=1) and this [IdeaExchange idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LmluQAC).

Confirmed as of the Winter '20 release.  Crazy that this still hasn't been prioritized...

Answer (score 0):

**Update as of 2-Nov-2021**

Now we simply have the button available for cases.

Starting in Spring'21 release (around 27-Feb-2021), the Manual Sharing became available in Lightning Experience: [Share Records with Manual Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_manual_sharing_lex.htm&type=5&release=230) not requiring custom solutions for accounts, opportunities, cases, contacts, leads, and custom objects.